# for each word in textbox do this code

Tags: vb.net, text, select-case

I have a problem with vb. I cant do this

```
 For Each Letter As Char In TextBox1.Text

    Select Case TextBox1.Text

      Case "run"
       'Code
      Case "ok"
       'Code

    End Select

Next
```

so what it does is it repeats for the amount of characters in the word i just want it to do it once

Comment: so dont use a For Each

Comment: yeah but if i type in "ok run" it wont do anything

Comment: but if i have "run run" it will only do it once

Comment: "ok run" <> "run"; if whatever is in the text box matches one of those case statements it will run ("ounce")

Comment: i meant to say once like 1 time. but what i want it to do is this if i type in "run ok run ok" it will play a sound that is run then ok then run then ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the `TextBox1.Text` contents into words, and loop over the words:

```
For Each word As String In TextBox1.Text.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Select Case word
        Case "run"
            'Code
        Case "ok"
            'Code
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Did not see your answer. Getting use to iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

**Parse the text into an array of words using space as your delimiter. You can then use a for loop and your Case statement.**

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim aryText() As String
'SPLIT THE TEXT INTO AN ARRAY' 
aryText = TextBox1.Text.Split(" "c )

For i = 0 To UBound(aryText)
       Select Case aryText(i)

          Case "run"
           'Code
          Case "ok"
           'Code

        End Select
Next
```